# How do I control the brightness of the backlight in android immediately?

Tags: android, performance, brightness, backlight

I'm working on an app that needs to turn on and turn off the backlight of the screen fast, very fast.
Something like off for 10ms, and then on for +-1ms.
I have tried to use this code with a handler and a runnable:

```
fieldScreenBrightness.setFloat(lp, brightness);
this.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

It work's fine, but not fast enough. It takes like 2 seconds to change the brightness from 0 to 1.
I know for sure there is a different way to do that because there are apps that makes the screen work as a strobe light.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The strobe light apps don't alter the brightness of the screen. They alter the color, usually alternating between black and white backgrounds very quickly. You should do that if your aim is to make a strobe light.

Comment: I know that solution, but my idea isnt a strobe light. I want the backlight to blink because the response time of the lcd is slower than the backlight keds. I want the screen to "flash" while im moving the device, leaving sharp trails in the air. Currently i get smudged result.